# Sequelize create TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, vuejs2, sequelize.js

I'm trying to insert a simple user object into a mysql database using sequelize orm.

[User model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJOoR.png)

[body payload & error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7ihm.png)

Insert code:

```
try {
   const { body } = req
   const user = await User.create(body) // It's breaking here :(

   const userJson = user.toJSON()
   res.send({
     user: userJson,
     token: jwtSignUser(userJson)
   })
  } catch (err) {
   res.status(400).send({
   error: 'Something went wrong!'
 })
```

Comment: Can you add your insert code here so that i will check it

Comment: @Priyank please see updated post with the insert code.

Comment: console.log your body before create and check what you get in it

Comment: @Priyank Please view the body payload on this screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7ihm.png

Comment: remove refferal_number from the body and check the output.

Comment: or did mentioned change in you model file
refferal_number : {
       DataTypes : STRING,
       allowNull: true,
}

Comment: @Priyank same error

Comment: what is the hasPassword in the hooks, did you include any module in the model files ?

Also check your node version

Comment: I'm using bluebird for promises. `hashPassword` is a private function that encrypts the user password.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have not defined the `hooks` correctly. They are supposed to be functions and I do not see `hashPassword` being defined in the code that has been shared.

From the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html)

```
hooks: {
    beforeValidate: (user, options) => {
      user.mood = 'happy';
    },
    afterValidate: (user, options) => {
      user.username = 'Toni';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ahh thanks @AbhinavD, it turns out that I wasn't referencing my hashPassword function which was in another file :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the reference to `hashPassword` function declaration is correct if it's in a different file :)